# How to manage sessions in a distributed application

Tags: java, session, virtual-machine, distributed-computing

I have a Java web application which is deployed on two VMs. and NLB (Network Load Balancing) is set for these VMs. My Application uses sessions. I am confused that how the user session is managed in both VMs. i.e. For Example- If I make a request that goes to VM1 and create a user session. Now the second time I make request and it goes to VM2 and want to access the session data. How would it find the session which has been created in VM1.

Please Help me to clear this confusion.

Comment: the most common approach is "sticky sessions" where the load balancer directs traffic to the server on which the session was created. if a server goes down the session is lost. EC2 can be set up to allow the sessions to complete before decommissioning a machine. Another solution is to cluster the sessions, but this will be a feature of the application server / technology you are building you application on.  Or have the application store session info in a database. Another solution is to make your application sessionless to begin with.

Comment: also, what JB said :)

Comment: Another solution I see more often in the distributed solution, having a separate Redis server(or cluster) and after successful login, creating and storing the session details of the users of your application there, next time when next user request comes, fetch respective user session-related information from Redis and update it with new info. As the session info is outside of your server so irrespective of which server creates the request, session information will be available.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several solutions:

- configure the load balancer to be sticky: i.e. requests belonging to the same session would always go to the same VM. The advantage is that this solution is simple. The disadvantage is that if one VM fails, half of the users lose their session
- configure the servers to use persistent sessions. If sessions are saved to a central database and loaded from this central database, then both VMs will see the same data in the session. You might still want to have sticky sessions to avoid concurrent accesses to the same session
- configure the servers in a cluster, and to distribute/replicate the sessions on all the nodes of the cluster
- avoid using sessions, and just use an signed cookie to identify the users (and possibly contain a few additional information). A JSON web token could be a good solution. Get everything else from the database when you need it. This ensures scalability and failover, and, IMO, often makes things simpler on the server instead of making it more complicated.

You'll have to look in the documentation of your server to see what is possible with that server, or use a third-party solution.

Comment: Extension to the 3rd point: In Weblogic, if we configure the servers in a cluster, does the sessions automatically distribute/replicate across nodes ? or do we need to externally set up something ? Also can you help with any doc/link on the same ?

Comment: need to do lots of research in all these points. Thanks @JB Nizet for the help.

Comment: I've not used WebLogic for years, sorry.

Comment: The big problem with JSON web tokens ie stateless is sychronized logging out of multiple domains. Without some kind of session service/repo its difficult to know if the user is logged out or not.

Answer (score -2):

We can use distributed Redis to store the session and that could solve this problem.

Comment: While this tool may help answer the question, it would be better to include an _example_ of how it is applicable to the problem with some _explanation_ regarding how it works. [Learn more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605)